# What is the minimum spring boot version that is compatible with the RestTemplate that has security configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-oauth2

So we know that in SpringBoot 3.0.x the OAuth2RestTemplate gets deprecated, making a lot of folks use WebClient as a means of making API calls with Security

However, the RestTemplate (import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;) library itself (note that WebClient is from reactive and different from the `web.client` you see in that import statement) was updated to include integrated security.

What do I mean by integrated security?
A lot of folks used to have one RestTemplate fetch tokens and another to make API calls. Ingrated Security means one RestTemplate can do both (via Security configuration)

I tried migrating to Spring Boot 3.0.1 from 2.5.14 but the amount of breaking changes begs the question: need I only bump up to, say, 2.7

Comment: What is the version number of when they first updated RestTemplate as you have described?

Comment: If it seems like I'm talking to myself, the other person deleted their comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer surprisingly is version `2.5.14`

So code-wise, one would put:
The build.gradle of the consuming app:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.14'
}
```

The build.gradle of the starter:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.14')
}
```